# Node/Express: GET request - 304

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making a GET request to get user (by user id) but I'm receiving a 304 status code.

How would I solve this?

routes/user.js

```
...
router.get('/secret/:userId', requireSignin, (req, res) => {
  console.log('id retrieved')
})

router.param('userId', userById)
```

controllers/user.js

```
const User = require("../models/User");

exports.userById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    User.findById(id).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'User not found'
            });
        }
    res.json(user)
    console.log("id retrieved successfully")
        next();
    });
};
```

controllers/auth.js

```
exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
    userProperty: 'auth'
});

exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    let user = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: 'Access denied'
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

Comment: Do you have any middleware in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304

> The HTTP 304 Not Modified client redirection response code indicates
> that there is no need to retransmit the requested resources. It is an
> implicit redirection to a cached resource.

It means that the server tells the client that he can use a cached entity. It saved a lot of transportation.

It is done behind the scenes even if you return 200 (`res.json` is 200 status code by default) explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that it's fine to receive a 304 status code instead of 200 or do I need to ensure that I receive 200?  @NaorLevi

Comment: It's totally ok.

Answer (score 0):

because you have 4 parameters in yow route. they have to be three.

- path.
- array of middlewares.
- endpoint.

```js
router.get('/myblog/:userId', [requireSignin, isAuth], listPostsBySignedInUser)
```

thats for the router. also the middlewares syntaxis is

```js
function (req, res, next) {...}
```

if you have a middleware with 4 parameters such as

```js
exports.userById = (req, res, next, id) => {
```

to you it looks like that, but for express and its conventions it looks like this

```js
exports.userById = (error, request, response, next) => {}
```

not only on express but on JS every first parameter will contain the error

Answer (score 0):

in your "controller/user.js" you need change
from:

```
res.json(user)
```

to

```
req.profile = user
```